# Read a Section of Lines from a File in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, head

I'm trying to export lines 100 to 1,000,100 from a file with 62 million lines. So far I've found this command:

```
head -1100000 input > output
```

But head does not take an offset option.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Combine `head` with `tail`:

```
tail -n+100 input | head -n1000000 > output
```

You can also use `sed`:

```
sed -n '100,1000100p' input > output
```

Comment: That's the one that came to mind for me as well, but there's probably a way to do it with a single '`sed`' command.

Comment: @UtahJarhead: See update :)

Comment: nevermind, that was your edit.  ;)